# If attribute exists, remove it and put its value as element's value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to remove specific attributes and put their values as element values surrounded by #.

My knowledge of XSLT is, unfortunately, so elementary that I could not translate any similar question to something that I could use.

Whatever I put inside

```
<xsl:template match="@Attr">
</xsl:template>
```

just deletes the attribute.

In short, XML like:

```
<Parent>
   <Elem1 Attr="Something" OtherAttr="Other">ExistingValue</Elem1>
   <Elem2 Attr="SomethingElse" />
</Parent>
```

should become:

```
<Parent>
   <Elem1 OtherAttr="Other">#Something#</Elem1>
   <Elem2>#SomethingElse#</Elem2>
</Parent>
```

If an element already has a value it should be replaced. Attributes other than one named `Attr`, if they exist, should be left unchanged. Elements that don't have attribute `Attr` should be left unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an element already has a value it should be replaced.

If you want to modify the element, you must operate on the element, not on the attribute.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@Attr]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='Attr')]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('#', @Attr, '#')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[@Attr]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @Attr"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Attr"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This question is tagged `xslt-1.0`. Your solution requires XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I used XSLT but something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, only specific nodes that have an attribute with the specific name should be modified. The rest should be left as is. I edited the question to make it clear.